# TYPO3 user rights: default startPage after BE-login

Tags: typo3, backend, tsconfig, usergroups

Is there a possibility to show a specific page AND modul after BE-login?

In User-TSConfig i can choose a startup-modul but there is not an option for a default startPage (pid)

```
setup.defaults.startModule = web_layout
setup.override.startModule = web_layout
```

Thus, the BE-user always receives the following message after login:

There are no records on this page.
Because the user hase no access to the root pid (0) and the records are in a different folder.

[image]

Comment: Can't you add the page as DB Mount for the user or usergroup? Or am I misunderstanding the problem here?

Comment: I added a screenshot to better illustrate the behavior. I'm looking for a solution that the user is not starting in PID 0 (New TYPO3 site) after login. instead the user should start in "mount"